# Sharing entity types across multiple edmx files

Tags: entity-framework, poco

We are using Entity Framework 4 with the POCO Entity Generator. Until now we've just had one .edmx file but we're running into performance problems due to the current size of it (well over 100 entities).

I understand we should be looking to break this into a series of .edmx files which is fine with one exception. We would want to somehow share certain entity types across two or more of these contexts. For example a User class is associated with numerous otherwise unrelated entities throughout our model.

So is it possible to have, say, a security model with its own .edmx and namespace for generated POCOs, but use it in another .emdx? If not I'm concerned we'll have multiple classes modelling the same database table which will need to be updated in sync with the database. I'd say that would be unworkable. (We're using database-first).

Obviously if I'm barking up the wrong tree do let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory you can have single POCO class used with multiple EDMX mappings because the mapping and class must match only in the name and name/types of properties. In practice this has some limitations. Just few I can think about:

- You cannot use automatic code generators with this approach unless you modify generator for every EDMX and make sure that every entity will be generated by just single generator from single EDMX. This directly points to second limitation.
- Entity must be exactly same in every EDMX. Including navigation properties. If it is not you will not be able to generate it at all without building your own code generation solution. What is worse if dynamic proxies demand that class with unique name is mapped only once. If you have two or more different mappings for the same class you will not be able to use dynamic proxies (lazy loading, dynamic change tracking) with only single mapping per application run.

Comment: Thank you Ladislav. I suspected it wouldn't be straight forward. I'll mark this as answer but would appreciate one further tip. Is there anywhere you can point me which would help me understand how to write a custom code generator for EDMX? Thanks again.